# Fix the link of "# all time messages by (John Doe)" in chat

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, chat-search

I've noticed that there is a link of "all time messages" either in the "frequently in rooms" or "currently in rooms" tabs in chat. But upon clicking on it, you will reach just to the usual transcript of the current day of this specific chat room. We already have an option to see the transcript, so this is either a bug or a misleading name for the link.

It will be actually really nice to see a certain users **all messages - all time**, as currently I'm not aware of a way of doing this (using search doesn't help because you also need to specify "containing" or "searching for". Neither the "recent" tab supplies all time information obviously).

[image]

Comment: similar or related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274106/158100

Comment: @rene the linked question is more of a feature-request, while this seem like a bug in an already existing feature... Have you any idea what this `"all time messages"` button meant for btw?

Comment: I think it was meant for what you expect it to do but never got implemented. We have to wait for @balpha to explain the exact reasons.