# Is it possible to search for words containing accented characters in chat?

Tags: bug, chat, unicode, chat-search

If I remember correctly, on the main site the search is "accent-blind" in the sense that, for example, searching for [José](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Jos%C3%A9) and [Jose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Jose) returns the same set of result. (Perhaps in different orders, exact matches might be considered more relevant.) Similarly for [François](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fran%C3%A7ois) and [Francois](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Francois).<sup>1</sup>

However, when I search in chat, searching for [Jose](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Jose) does not return messages containing José. I am not sure how exactly are the messages returned when searching for [José](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Jos%C3%A9) selected. But when I actually want to find messages containing the word José, I have to search for [Jos](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Jos).

Similarly, if I want to find messages containing the name François, I have to search for [Fran](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fran) or [ois](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=ois). (In short, this works as if the word was a part between two accented characters, or if there is only one then between the accented character and the beginning/end of the word.) I get completely different sets of results for [François](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fran%C3%A7ois) and for [Francois](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Francois).

If the word contains more accents, search seems to be more complicated. I have just tested [in the sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1/2018/10/28) that messages containing the name Désirée are found when searching for [sir](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=sir&user=11287&room=1). They are not among the results if I search for [Désirée](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=D%C3%A9sir%C3%A9e&user=11287&room=1) or [Desiree](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Desiree&user=11287&room=1), that message is not among the search results.

- Is it actually possible to search in chat for words including accented characters (such as the examples above)? Did I miss some trick I should have used?
- If not, could some similar functionality as in the search of main be implemented.

I suppose that if there is name with accented characters, some users will use it in that way and some will transcribe it. (Especially if something is copy-pasted from somewhere, it is likely to contain accented characters.) If somebody is looking for past messages containing this name, AFAICT they have to do several searches.

<sup>1</sup>See, for example, this feature request which is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): [Search is too accent-sensitive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133336).

Comment: If everything else fails, consider using a [script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274146/158100) (that one is mine, for a slightly different purpose but it can fetch all messages of a single room and inspect its content). I don't claim that script is awesome ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chat search is broken for words with diacritics, like "ingénieurs"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338782/chat-search-is-broken-for-words-with-diacritics-like-ing%c3%a9nieurs)