# Chat search is broken for words with diacritics, like "ingénieurs"

Tags: bug, chat, unicode, chat-search

Chat search is broken for words containing letters with diacritics on them cannot be matched. Indeed, these are even considered "word boundaries" themselves!

For example, searching the French Language chatroom, Chez Cosette, for any *ingénieurs* [yields 0 hits](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=ing%C3%A9nieurs&user=&room=1098). That’s because internally something is messing up with Unicode and treating `ingénieurs` as `‹ing›‹é›‹nieurs›`, where I've used angle brackets to denote word boundaries. It’s not matching complete words when it should.

This is easily proven by searching either [for *ing*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=ing&user=&room=1098) or [for *nieurs*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=nieurs&user=&room=1098).  Notice how now it’s matching incomplete words when it shouldn’t. So that’s two kinds of problem.

This is a real bother, filled with false negatives and false positives depending how you go at it. It isn’t a problem with regular site-search, which does all this correctly. One should be able to search for words with diacritical markings in them in our chat rooms just as one can on our regular sites.

Comment: The obvious solution is to switch to EBCDIC!

Comment: @Ward-ReinstateMonica Dude! If you thought `[a-z]` was bad before, just wait till you see it under EBCDIC! :)

Comment: I'm oooooolllllddd... I've used IBM mainframes.

Comment: @Ward-ReinstateMonica So am I, and so have I. What I don't understand is downvotes on a legitimate bug report about a real issue that interferes with basic search. I hope it isn't anti-French bigotry.

Comment: Assuming or implying bigotry is in itself a form of bigotry. Maybe someone misunderstrood the bug report, or someone may think the problem is not significant enough... Either way, it's just two votes.

Comment: Isn't it the same as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317364/is-it-possible-to-search-for-words-containing-accented-characters-in-chat)?

Comment: Chat search is dreadfully broken. It doesn't work for apostrophes either (try searching `al'thor`, or anything else apostrophised, in chat and you'll find only oneboxes).

Comment: @gerrit Yes, kinda. But that's allegedly a feature request rather than a bug report. And trust me, this is a bug not a feature. :)

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard That one is a feature request asking to make chat search work for Unicode.

Comment: There's a request to [add ElasticSearch to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160110/282094) which was favored but not implemented.